# What is the proper way to use services in Angular4?

Tags: angular

I ask this because I’m new in Angular4, and the thing for me is: Should I use a service inside a model. e.g. a simple class for a type stucture or inside a component? My doubt comes from a stackoverflow answer, that said that a component is similar to the C in MVC.

Comment: For the highest success with this very fun and full featured framework, and to be more effective and efficient over time, I'd recommend spending some time up front learning. There is a good tutorial in the docs at angular.io or if you prefer videos, I have a training course here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update/table-of-contents (You can sign up for a free week trial.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it in both places. Inside model for (type structure) and inside component using DI.

The difference comes with the usage. Use a Class as a simple class or use it as an Injectable class using DI. Its all about what you need. Nothing wrong in using it in multiple places.

Comment: My fear is that can become to much injectable. Injectable class, injectable service ...

Answer (score 0):

The View (Template) depends on the Model (Json Objects) for data; the View also depends on the Controller (Component Class) for methods (Click Handlers). The Controller (Component Class) knows about the Models (Json Objects); the Controller depends on Services (Dependency Injected) to get the Data (Json Objects).

So, a service should be dependency injected into a Component class. Setup the dependency injection within your module.